# pyparsing infix notation with non-grouping parentheses

Tags: python, pyparsing, lexical-analysis, infix-notation

I'm working on a billing application where users can enter arbitrary mathematical expressions. For example, a line item might be defined as `(a + b) * c`.

pyparsing handles the order of operations well enough in this case:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

operand = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
boolean_operator = pp.one_of(['||', '&&'])
comparison_operator = pp.one_of(['<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!='])

infix_pattern = pp.infix_notation(
    operand,
    [
        ('^', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        ('*', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        ('/', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        ('+', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        ('-', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (comparison_operator, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (boolean_operator, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
    ]
)

print(infix_pattern.parse_string('(a + b) * c'))
# [[['a', '+', 'b'], '*', 'c']]
```

Users can also enter a handful of well-known functions, including the calling parentheses and arguments. For example, if a line item is defined as `a(b) == c(d)`, pyparsing gets confused:

```
print(infix_pattern.parse_string('a(b) == c(d)'))
# ['a']
```

What I would like to see in this case is `['a(b)', '==', 'c(d)']`. What do I need to do differently in order to keep the first example working as-is and get the desired behavior from the second example?

Comment: Your original grammar gives  `*` a higher precedence than `/`, so `a/b*c` will parse as though it had been written `a/(b*c)`. That's unconventional. (Perhaps a more intuitive counter-example would be `a/b*c/d`. which would turn out to have the same value as `(a/b)*(d/c)` rather than `(a/b)*(c/d)`. Leaving that niggle aside, what you need to do is modify your syntax for `operand` so that function calls are included.

Comment: @rici originally I had `operand = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '()')` but that broke the group precedence. Is there another syntax that would only match if the parens come after a name?

Comment: Well, yeah. `pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '()')` matches any word consisting of letters, digits, and parentheses. Such as `(33`. So that can't be right. A function call can't be described as though it were a token using a regular expression. It's a complex, perhaps nested, tree of objects. Look at the [Excel expression](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/excelExpr.py) example for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I got it:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

operand = pp.Word(pp.alphanums) + pp.Opt(pp.Literal('(') + ... + pp.Literal(')'))
boolean_operator = pp.one_of(['||', '&&'])
comparison_operator = pp.one_of(['<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!='])

infix_pattern = pp.infix_notation(
    operand,
    [
        ('^', 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (pp.one_of(['*', '/']), 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (pp.one_of(['+', '-']), 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (comparison_operator, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
        (boolean_operator, 2, pp.OpAssoc.LEFT),
    ]
)

print(infix_pattern.parse_string('(a + b) * c'))
# [[['a', '+', 'b'], '*', 'c']]

print(infix_pattern.parse_string('a(b) == c(d)'))
# [['a', '(', 'b', ')', '==', 'c', '(', 'd', ')']]
```

I could combine the `a(b)` and `c(d)` with `pp.Combine` or something but this is fine.

Comment: This is only a partial solution, and fails when you have a nested function call like `a(b(c))`. You can see how function calls are handled in the plusminus package https://github.com/pyparsing/plusminus/blob/master/plusminus/plusminus.py